# Issue when importing kivy.core.window and using the multiprocessing library

Tags: python, kivy, python-multiprocessing

First of all, I'd like to clarify that I have absolutely 0 background as a software engineer and this is the first time I'm using python for something besides API's and creating excel/plots.

My issue is that I was trying to create an app using kivy and then I imported the `kivy.core.window` library a blank screen appears.

I've seen that this issue is fairly common when using kivy and multiprocessing, but none of the information I found fixed my problem. Result of running my code without the `kivy.core.window` library:

[image]

Result when adding said library:

[image]

Also, if I wait like 10 seconds the blank screen disappears and kills the count_time process.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
import time
from datetime import datetime
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, freeze_support

Builder.load_string('''
<TestScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical" # place object vertically
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'TITLE'
            font_size: 150
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Button:
            text: 'start'
            on_press: root.start_mp()
        Button:
            text: 'stop'
            on_press: root.stop_time()
''')

def count_time(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print('count={}'.format(i))
        time.sleep(1)

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        sm.add_widget(TestScreen(name='test'))
        return sm

class TestScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def start_mp(self):
        self.p1 = mp.Process(target=count_time, args=(10, ))
        self.p1.start()

    def stop_time(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
    Test().run()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. What are you doing with the `kivy.core.window`?

Comment: I import kivy.core.window like so:

```import kivy.core.window as Window```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you run `Process`, it starts a new python proces and imports the current `.py` file. On most platforms, the line:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

protects the `Test().run()` from being executed and starting another `App` and is enough to protect from another window being opened. However, it appears that importing `kivy.core.window` is enough to open another window (on Windows platform) when the original `.py` file is imported for multiprocessing. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4744).

A really ugly work around is to protect all kivy imports (and as a result, all the kivy code) with a `if __name__ == '__main__':` line. Like this:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def count_time(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print('count={}'.format(i))
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition

    Builder.load_string('''
<TestScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical" # place object vertically
        Label:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            text: 'TITLE'
            font_size: 150
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Button:
            text: 'start'
            on_press: root.start_mp()
        Button:
            text: 'stop'
            on_press: root.stop_time()
    ''')


    class Test(App):

        def build(self):
            sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
            sm.add_widget(TestScreen(name='test'))
            return sm


    class TestScreen(Screen):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(TestScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def start_mp(self):
            self.p1 = mp.Process(target=count_time, args=(10,))
            self.p1.start()

        def stop_time(self):
            pass


    Test().run()
```

Comment: I believe you can make it look a bit cleaner by using separate `.py` files and playing the `import` game: file1 imports the kivy code file (with protection), and that kivy code file imports file1 (yes, circular imports sometimes work).